# When the test execution is failed, can we rerun the failed test case immediately using Specflow

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow

If an element is not found in a test case, then it is failed. again it should run from the failed step that is finding the element again immediately instead of moving to next step. Is it possible using Selenium with C# specflow. kindly let me know if possible with example

Comment: Can you please provide your current code implementation so that I can help? There are several ways that we can achieve this functionality. Generally if an element cannot be found, it is more than likely a timing issue, where the code may try to find the element before actually rendering. We can use 'explicit wait' for this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually it is not about the timing issue we just starting developing the automation in our organization. we have been trying the multiple cases, similarly if it is not about the timeout if element name is wrong then we can rerun the step immediately by not moving to next step or running the failed cases later. hope you understood my intention if not please let me know

Comment: If the element name is wrong then you need to update it within your code. However, you could place your code in a try/catch block and catch the exception and try to re-find the element. Please share your code as your question is very vague and does not provide enough information. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have enough information. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].